# Dynamically change the handle option in the stop event

Tags: jquery-ui

All,I knew how to use the [`handle`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle) in the Jquery UI draggable and sortable. And I also knew we can modify the dragged item html content and css style in the stop event. But I don't know If there is any possibility to dynamically add a handle selector to the drag item in the stop event? please review the below code . thanks.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable : '.sortableDiv',

  stop: function( event, ui ) {
      //do nothing

  }
});

$(".sortableDiv").sortable({
  stop:function(event,ui){
    $(ui.item).prependTo(
         $('<div>drag handler</div>').addClass('draghandler'));//append elements
      //next I want to make the div.draghandler to be the drag handle .

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it. Just add the handle option no matter whether the selector can retrieve any elements for it. If doesn't find any element there is no handle for drag . otherwise it will works. Please review the code. thanks.

```
$(".sortableDiv").sortable({
  stop:function(event,ui){
    $(ui.item).prependTo(
         $('<div>drag handler</div>').addClass('draghandler'));//append elements
      //next I want to make the div.draghandler to be the drag handle .

  },
  handle:'div.draghangler'
});
```

That means the handle selector can works on the future elements.